# Why does the 'indexOf' method of my own 'LinkedList' class return an incorrect index?

Tags: java, linked-list, indexof

Hello I am having trouble coding the `indexOf` method of this `LinkedList` of objects. Everytime I tried to return "index" it returns 3 which is false because I only have 3 numbers in the list and the index starts at 0 so the highest index would be 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedList<E>
{
    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    protected class Node<E> {
        public Object data;
        public Node<E> next;
        public Node(Object data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    protected Node<E> first = null;

    public void prepend(Object e)
    {
        Node<E> newnode = new Node<E>(e);
        newnode.next = first;
        first = newnode;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Node<E> current = first;

        while (current != null)
        {
            System.out.println(index);
            if (current == e)
            {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.prepend(new Integer(1));
        list.prepend(new Integer(2));
        list.prepend(new Integer(3));
        System.out.println(list.indexOf(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns "-1" for me and I wonder how your current code could find something, since it doesn't compare the nodes correctly. It doesn't even compare *nodes*, only one node against a number, which obviously can't work.

Comment: I'd like to make two more suggestions on your code above: "public Object data" might be best as "public E data".  And pass parameter type "E" for "prepend" and "indexOf" methods.  I looks like this might be your intended use of the generics.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (current==(e))
```

will need to be

```
if (current.data.equals(e))
```

for one.  But this does not explain how you'd get 3 as a result.

Clarification:

"But this does not explain how you'd get 3 as a result."

I'm not sure the O.P. is actually getting 3 as a result.  Looking at the code I found the apparent bug, but question their understanding and phrasing of their original question.

With that in mind, this was meant as a complete answer.

Comment: Could you mention this 'bug' because right now it's still unclear what the answer really is.

Comment: Revised: "if (current.data.equals(e))".  I can see by my inaccuracy and intolerance that I need sleep.  Good night ya'all.